# php insert albumID into my music store

Tags: php, database, mysqli, insert

I have this music store, when I want to add a new album It also has to insert the albumID which in the table of "artiesten" somehow I don't get it. Does anyone has a solution?

Here is the image of my database : https://gyazo.com/64ebabed8655cb204d8d7223f92dfc46

Here is the code of the album review :

```
$db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass,$database);
if($db){
    $h.= "";
    $h.= "<form><table class='table table-striped table-hover'>";
    $h.= "<tr>";
    $h.= "<th>Nr.</th>";
    $h.= "<th>Albums</th>";
    $h.= "<th>Artiest</th>";
    $h.= "<th>Nummer</th>";
    $h.= "<th></th>";
    $h.='<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">';
    $h.="   <li role='presentation' class='active'><a href='http://localhost:8888/?action=album '>Albums<span class='badge'></span></a></li>";
    $h.='   <li role="presentation"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?action=songs">Songs</a></li>';
    //$h.='<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary style="float: right"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?action=add-album">';
    $h.= "<td style='text-align:right;'><a href='/?action=add-album&albumid=".$_GET['id']."' class='btn btn-primary'>VOEG TOE</a></td>";

    $h.='</ul>';
    $h.="<br>";
    $h.= "</tr>";   

    $sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM albums");
    $sql1 = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM artiesten");

    if($sql){

    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0) {  //if you have some albums to print...

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

            //start printing a row
            $h.= "<tr>";
            $h.= "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
            $h.= "<td>".$row['albumName']."</td>";

            //now get the artiest for the album by querying the correct albumid
            $albumid = $row['id'];
            $sql1 = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM artiesten WHERE albumID = '$albumid' ");

            while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1)){

                 $h.= "<td>".$row1['artiest']."</td>";  //print the right artiest
            }

            $h.= "<td style='text-align:right;'><a href='/?action=show-songs&id=".$row['id']."'' class='btn btn-primary'>Zie nummers</a>&nbsp";
            $h.= "<style='text-align:right;'><a href='/?action=delete-album&id=".$row['id']."'' class='btn btn-danger'>VERWIJDER</a></td>";
            $h.= "</tr>";

        }   

        }else{

            echo "<tr>No Recore Found</tr>";

        }

        $h.= "</table></form>";

    echo $htop;
    echo $h;
    echo $hbot;

    }
```

and here is the code when I add a new album :

```
    $db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass,$database);

    if($_GET['action2'] == "1"){

        mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO artiesten (artiest, albumID) VALUES ('".$_GET['artiestnaam']."')"); 
        mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO albums (albumName) VALUES ('".$_GET['albumnaam']."')");                   
        header("Location: /?action=album");

    }

    $h = "";
    $h.= "";

    $h.= "<form><input type='hidden' name='action' value='add-album'><input type='hidden' name='action2' value='1'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$_GET['id']."'><table class='table table-striped'>";
    $h.= "  <tr>";
    $h.= "      <td><b>Artiest naam</b></td>";
    $h.= "      <td><input type='text' name='artiestnaam' class='form-control' placeholder='Naam'></td>";
    $h.= "  </tr>";
    $h.= "  <tr>";
    $h.= "      <td><b>Album naam</b></td>";
    $h.= "      <td><input type='text' name='albumnaam' class='form-control' placeholder='Naam'></td>";
    $h.= "  </tr>";
    $h.= "  <tr>";
    $h.= "      <td colspan='2'><input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='UPDATE'></td>";
    $h.= "  </tr>";
    $h.= "</table></form>";

    echo $htop;
    echo $h;
    echo $hbot;
```

hope anyone will find a solution

Comment: Couldn't understand 100% your problem. Could you explain it better?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos i have a album review , if I want to add a new album I added a button "voeg toe" which means add. Then I have 2 textfields ,one to add an artiest and one to add an album. When I put something in the textfield in "artiest" for example "bob" it should be inserting an id , name and also a albumID because it is linked to my albums each album has their own albumID but I don't get how.

Comment: Do you have any errors? Put these lines on the top of the file and run it again - `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` If you have any errors please edit your question and add them.

Comment: Your artiesten table requires artiest and albumID, you are only inserting one value ($_GET['artiestnaam']) though. You probably need to insert into albumn first, to get the albumID

Comment: I have 2 errors , the first one on the page "album" : Notice: Undefined index: id in /Users/Users/Desktop/index.php on line 188. and the second one on the page "add-album" : Notice: Undefined index: id in /Users/Users/Desktop/index.php on line 152

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos

Comment: Are you sure `$_GET['id']` is set? Try to `print_r($_GET['id']);` before starting the sql query

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos didn't get any result

Comment: So `$_GET['id']` is not set - this is what "undefined index : id" means. What is the url that you hit so this code can run? It should be for example `www.mysite.com/?id=1`

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos it is the id I try to get for each albumID here is the line : "$h.= "<form><input type='hidden' name='action' value='add-album'><input type='hidden' name='action2' value='1'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$_GET['id']."'><table class='table table-striped'>";

Comment: Yes i can see that, but that value is `null`. Try replacing `$_GET['id']` with and albumID that exists in database just to see what will happen.

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I did "1" it added the album1 without the artiest name

Comment: Because it is probably `null`. What is the name of the .php file of the first block? What is the url that you hit to trigger that .php file to get executed?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos what you mean trigger?

Comment: when you hit  for example `www.mysite.com/myphpfile.php` this code will run. What is the URL that you use?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I use mmamp  this is the url when I add a album " http://localhost:8888/?action=add-album "

Comment: You will have to use `localhost:8888/?action=add-album?id=5` . Then `$_GET['id']` will have the value `5` . Another example `www.mysite.com/myphpfile?name=John` . The `$_GET['name']` will have value `John`

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos you mean I have to print the id ?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos yes I know it will get the value " but I don't get any result because it will insert"

Comment: It will insert but your values are `null` - this is why you can't insert to database. Watch the errors that you get.

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos oh okay I see it now

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos do you maybe have solution how I can fix this?

Comment: No i can't really give you an answer because i don't know what exactly you  call and how. Have you tried anything else? I've told you that $_GET['id'] is null so you should search why it is null..

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos alright thanks for you help !